# Child does not occupy 100% width of its parent

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using TailwindCSS and trying to implement a shimmer effect for an item card component.
I'm trying to build exactly the same item card but with static data to be replaced while the dynamic data is being fetched. the problem is although I'm using h-full and w-full it does not occupy 100% width of its parent.

[image: Edit Tailwind Css and React (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

Add `w-full` to the parent div

```
  <div className="md:h-5/6 md:w-9/10 w-full rounded relative "> // w-full here
        {!imageLoaded && <ItemCardShimmer />}
        <img
          className={`object-cover rounded-lg w-full h-full ${
            imageLoaded ? "block" : "hidden"
          }`}
          src="https://source.unsplash.com/250x300/?product"
          alt="Item to buy"
          onLoad={() => setImageLoaded(true)}
        />
        <div className="absolute bottom-0 left-0 w-full h-1/6 bg-black opacity-30"></div>
        <p className="absolute bottom-0 left-0 text-white text-2xl font-bold py-2 px-4">
          € 22
        </p>
      </div>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I think you got me wrong. When you refresh the page, a loading text with a red background is shown. I want that to be exactly the same size as the image. occupies. the whole width.

Comment: My bad, can you be more specific. You want the text to take the whole width as the image? Or you want the text to be placed in the center of the image position, or the background red spanning the complete width

Comment: I want the red background behind the loading text to be exactly the same size as the image. Then I'll center the loading text.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the second div and it worked like so:

```
<div className="md:w-2/5 md:h-9/10 rounded-lg bg-secondary flex justify-center items-center shadow-2xl">
  
    {!imageLoaded && <ItemCardShimmer />}
    <img
      className={`object-cover rounded-lg w-full h-full ${
        imageLoaded ? "block" : "hidden"
      }`}
      src="https://source.unsplash.com/250x300/?product"
      alt="Item to buy"
      onLoad={() => setImageLoaded(true)}
    />
    <div className="absolute bottom-0 left-0 w-full h-1/6 bg-black opacity-30"></div>
    <p className="absolute bottom-0 left-0 text-white text-2xl font-bold py-2 px-4">
      € 22
    </p>
  
</div>
```

Also if you want the red background to be full width and height of the Image before it loads up, just add 'height' property to the  element in ItemCardShimmer component and it will work. It worked for me.

Comment: Actually I need that div :)